# Is the age restriction lower in Japan than in western countries?

Tags: anime-history

For instance, the anime *Darker than Black* is R-17+ (violence & profanity) in the West, but is it higher or lower in Japan?

Comment: What type of media are you specifically referring to? Different media have different regulators.

Comment: i am referring to anime

Comment: Where are you seeing this rating?

Comment: As far as I know DTB has not been rated as "R - 17+ (violence & profanity)" by any Western TV ratings organization. [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0995941/parentalguide?ref_=tt_stry_pg#certification) doesn't list any such rating.

Comment: They have a rather different standard on profanity over there, one time Sonic the Hedgehog gives a very emphatic yell of "s**t" in an anime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The television rating system in Japan is the same as the [movie rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eirin).

Their regulations are as follows:

**Unrestricted**

- G: General audiences
- PG12: Parental guidance suggested. Some content may be unsuitable for children under the age of 12.

**Restricted**

These are regulated, and all movie theaters are required to check for ID. Allowing in an underage child is a criminal offense.

- R15+: Restricted to teenagers 15 and over only.
- R18+: Restricted to teenagers 18 and over only.

It is a lot more difficult to regulate television watching than to regulate movie-watching, so just because a rating is given for a television show, it doesn't mean that it is being followed, whereas in a movie theater, at least, it can be regulated. Frequently, in America, for TV-MA, a warning will be given that the show may not be appropriate for children under the age of 17.

Darker than Black was actually rated TV-MA in America, not R. R is only used for movies, and Darker than Black is a TV series. The rating is given [here](http://www.funimation.com/darker-than-black).

I cannot (at the moment) find what the Japanese rating is for Darker than Black, but presumably it was either R15+ or R18+.

Comment: Side note: R15+ isn't like the MPAA's R where you can get in if accompanied by a parent. Both R15+ and R18+ are strict no-entry, like the MPAA's NC-17.

Comment: Are you claiming that Eirin rates TV series as well as movies? I can't find any solid sources to back that up, including their own website. Even if they do, I'm not sure that late night anime get rated.

Comment: Both http://rating-system.wikia.com/wiki/Eirin and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_content_rating_systems#Japan say it, though they may be pulling from the same source/each other. I have no first hand experience, but it is from what I found.